# Convert Hexadecimal String to Integer

Tags: prolog

All I want is a predicate of the form

```
parse_hex(H, N).
```

which converts between a hexadecimal string and prolog integers. I could implement this myself, obviously, but I am wondering if there is a built in. I haven't been able to find one but it seems like there must be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that standard Prolog supports hexadecimal numbers, if by string you mean a Prolog atom:

```
parse_hex(H, N) :-
    atom_concat('0x', H, HexaAtom),
    atom_codes(HexaAtom, HexaCodes),
    number_codes(N, HexaCodes).
```

If you really have a string instead of an atom, see your Prolog documentation on converting it into an atom. E.g. SWI-Prolog provides an `atom_string/2` bi-directional built-in predicate.

Sample call:

```
?- parse_hex('ff', N).
N = 255.
```